# Display view from the top when go back in swift

Tags: ios, swift

When I scroll down and click on an image in Collection View, I navigate user profile screen with following code :

```
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("userProfilePage") as! userProfileScreen


    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have a button on user profile page to go back to the previous screen with following code :

```
@IBAction func goBack(sender: AnyObject) {
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
}
```

But, when I go back, previous screen display as is, I mean it display scrolled down to the image that I clicked. Is it possible to display screen from the top when I go back with dismissViewControllerAnimated ?

Comment: You can do the scrolling in the completion handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scroll to the top

```
mainTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated:true)
```

In the `viewWillAppear`, so every time it will display this screen, it will get to the top.